# Looping over weekday in python time object

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a dataset of drivers' travel diaries. For each trip there is an associated start time, end time and day of week in a csv file. There are no dates associated with the trips.

I have now got the data into python where each start time and end time has the weekday attached to it like so:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=23, 
                 tm_min=45, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)

print journey['BeginTime'][2].tm_wday, journey['BeginTime'][2].tm_hour
```

Which returns 0 for a Monday and 23 for the hour.

There's 11,000 of these trips and what I want to get is a weekly profile of the number of cars which are driving based on time of day.

This can be inferred by counting the number of trips that are between their respective ['BeginTime'] and ['EndTime'] interval over a specified time interval. A five minute interval is sufficient as the data is to the nearest five minutes.

Is there an elegant python way to do this? Something like:

```
for fiveMinutes in Week:
count = 0
    for trip in range(len(journey['BeginTime']):
        if journey['BeginTime'][trip] == fiveMinutes
               or (journey['BeginTime'][trip] < fiveMinutes 
                   and journey['EndTime'][trip] > fiveMinutes):
           count = count + 1
carCount[fiveMinutes] = count
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a dictionary with a bunch of lists in it.  Wouldn't it be better to use a list of dictionaries, with one dictionary per journey?

Comment: do you need to worry about journeys that cross a day boundary or a week boundary?

Comment: Thanks jcfollower. Re your first comment, you could be right! I have 5 csv files from the survey each of which cover a different aspect of the travel diaries connected by the unique user ID. I just wanted a quick way to import the data so I used this code, but what's the better way? def getCSVData(filename):
 data = csv.reader(open((filename),'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
 
 headers = data.next()
 column = {}
 for h in headers:
    column[h] = []    
 for row in data:
  for h, v in zip(headers, row):  
   column[h].append(v)
 return column

Comment: Re your second point, I have accounted for trips which go on different days in the python code, so a trip can start on a Monday at 11pm (tm_day=0) and finish on a Tuesday (tm_day=1) at 1am. Ideally I'd like a python way to have each 5 minute period in the loop be specific to a day which would then account for this. This would hopefully account for the Sunday/Monday boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps, here is an idea ...

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# This does not check for crossing from Sunday to Monday
def convert_dt(start_dt, journey):
    begin_weekday, begin_hour, begin_minute = journey[0]
    end_weekday, end_hour, end_minute = journey[1]

    begin_dt = start_dt + timedelta(days=begin_weekday)
    begin_dt += timedelta(hours=begin_hour, minutes=begin_minute)

    end_dt = start_dt + timedelta(days=end_weekday)
    end_dt += timedelta(hours=end_hour,minutes=end_minute)
    return (begin_dt, end_dt)

def get_slot_journeys(start_dt, journeys):           
    next_dt = start_dt
    slot_count =  60/5 * 24 * 7
    slot_dict = {}

    journey_dts = []
    #convert journey begin and end to datetimes
    for index in range(len(journeys['begin_weekday'])):
        next_journey = [(journeys['begin_weekday'][index],
                         journeys['begin_hour'][index],
                         journeys['begin_minute'][index],),
                        (journeys['end_weekday'][index],
                         journeys['end_hour'][index],
                         journeys['end_minute'][index],)
                       ]
        journey_dts.append(convert_dt(start_dt, next_journey))

    for slot in range(slot_count):
        slot_dict[next_dt] = 0
        for journey_start, journey_end in journey_dts:
            if next_dt >= journey_start and next_dt <= journey_end:
                slot_dict[next_dt] = slot_dict[next_dt] + 1                    

        next_dt += timedelta(minutes=(5))

    return slot_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_dt = datetime(2012, 1, 2, 0, 0)    

    journeys = {'begin_weekday': [0, 0],
                'begin_hour': [14, 18],
                'begin_minute': [20, 30],
                'end_weekday': [0, 1],
                'end_hour': [19, 12],
                'end_minute': [15, 55],
               }
    slot_dict = get_slot_journeys(start_dt, journeys)       
    slot_keys = slot_dict.keys()
    slot_keys.sort()

    for key in slot_keys:
        if slot_dict[key]:    
            print key, slot_dict[key]
```